# What are the default login credentials for Tiny Tiny RSS?

Tags: software-installation, tt-rss

I followed [this article to install Tiny Tiny RSS](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/how-to-install-tiny-tiny-rss-in-ubuntu.html) on my Ubuntu machine. Everything went well, but when I try to go to `http://localhost/tt-rss/` it asks for the username and password. Which username and password should I enter here, it didn't ask me to create one during installation?

Answer (score 2):

You can find that information in the [Installation Guide on Tiny Tiny RSS Wiki](http://tt-rss.org/redmine/projects/tt-rss/wiki/InstallationNotes#Installation-Guide)

> After finishing with the installer, open your Tiny Tiny RSS installation at http://your.site.com/tt-rss/ and login with default credentials (username: admin, password: password).

So the default username is `admin` and the default password is `password`. After logging, you should go to the preferences and change the password there.